# Reactjs: Do classes/prototypes have any place in our applications?

Tags: javascript, module, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

**An O.O Developer Making his Transition into a World of Modules**

Almost all of my JavaScript coding experience has been in React and almost everything I've built strictly uses React Components,Stores, Actions and Dispatcher.

**Outside of that, everything I try to abstract away I have placed into helper modules.(XUtils, YUtils WebAPIUtils, ect)**

---

**Where I got confused**

But yesterday I ran into an issue that showed me a gap my understanding of React because **I found myself wanting to create a helper class/prototype(however you like to encapsulate your code) to add to a component because the typical imported module would only have methods whereas I would need something that I could encapsulate variables.**

It didn't feel right,**but I can't explain why I feel like I can't plug in classes/prototypes into any part of my React code.**

**Question:**

**Should all of our helper classes to abstract away/delegate code be limited to modules? If so, can you explain a little bit of the philosophy behind why React programming is a world of modules?**

Comment: Bolding more than 50% of your question does not help emphasize, its just distracting to the reader.

Comment: I usually try to bold places to help readers skim the question and get a quick idea what the question was about. You're right though, this one was a little too much. I wish I had a highlighter, haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the typical imported module would only have methods whereas I would need something that I could encapsulate variables

Modules can export **anything**. This is intentional.

```
export const someConstant = 4;
export class SomeClass {}
export function someFunction() {}
```

Want to keep a bunch of variables in a module so you can share them between a bunch of other modules? Sounds like a config file/store, go for it. This is a solid pattern.

Want to create a module with a  factory function that returns class instances? Good idea, solid pattern.

Want to export a class from a module? This is what React recommends for its components. This pattern is explicitly encouraged by React, and is a good practice in general. Go for it.

> Should all of our helper classes to abstract away/delegate code be limited to modules?

You can put **anything** in a module, export it, and import it into another module. This is a good practice to follow because it creates encapsulation and allows code reuse. But, should this code be *limited* to modules? That's a strange question.

- Do you mean you want to abstract code without reusing it? I don't know what that looks like.
- Do you mean you want to abstract code and share it without it being a module? How are you sharing it?

Abstracting code into a module that is used by the rest of your application isn't a **limitation**. Its a **super-power**.

> can you explain a little bit of the philosophy behind why React programming is a world of modules?

Because **programming** is a world of modules. Modules give us code reuse (the [DRY pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), and [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) (a key feature of object-oriented programmning). Modules encourage testability by limiting the scope and surface area of code. Tested modules give developers *confidence* in their resuse. Modules are all upside.